# Linear mixed model with repeated measures at two timescales

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, sas

I want to use a Linear Mixed Model on the following design:  20 subjects with one between-subjects factor (10 males, 10 females).  Each subject is measured at 4 timepoints:  At 0 weeks, 2 weeks, 4 weeks, and 6 weeks.   There is a single dependent variable being measured (say, blood glucose concentration).

The kicker is that there are also duplicate measurements taken within each timepoint, within each subject.  E.g., Subject #1 at 0 weeks was measured twice, separated by about 10 minutes.   Thus the total number of data values over the entire study is 20 x 4 x 2 = 160.   Each subject has 8 measurements (4 timepoints with duplicates at each timepoint)

Technically speaking, there is only one time variable here, and there are 8 timepoints at roughly 0, 0.001, 2, 2.001, 4, 4.001, 6, and 6.001 weeks.   So I suppose this could just be set up as a typical repeated-measures design.

But is there a sexier way to do this?  Can there be a "nested" repeated measures factor such that the 2-week time scale is one factor, and the 10-minute separation between duplicates a second factor?  Surely there is some covariance information there that could be captured.

(I'm looking to do this in SAS, but general responses are appreciated too)